# call collection with other model to lists

Tags: laravel

How do I call the relational data in the statement below using a with statement.

```
$suppliers = Supplier::with('user')->lists('user.company', 'user.id'); // doesn't work

class Supplier extends Model
{
    protected $table = "suppliers";

    protected $fillable = ['email'];


    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'email', 'email');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve your goal using the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
Supplier::with('user')->get()->pluck ('user.company', 'user.id');
```

The get method returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections), then you can use its methods.